# How to add a Animator Controller to a character at runtime?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I have an Animator controller at "Assets/Resources/System/PLController". I have to add it at runtime using a script. How to accomplish this. Using Unity 5 (5.3.0f4)

PLController = (Animator Controller)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First attach an `Animator` component to that `GameObject` like

[image: Animator Component]

- Declare an `Animator` variable.
- Assign variable through `GetComponent`
- Assign `RuntimeAnimatorController` to its `runtimeAnimatorController` attribute.

Like,

```
Animator PLAnimator;

void Start ()
    {
        PLAnimator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
        PLAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load ("Assets/Resources/System/PLController") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hamza, It Worked like a charm.

Comment: What is the name of the file where this code exists? `PLController.controller`?

Comment: @PHPDeveloper its his own custom class