# can't create and save animation file in runtime unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a new animation clip file and set it in Animation component , that will be added to a GameObject in runtime.
something like this:

```
Animation addedAnim = fbxObject.AddComponent<Animation>() as Animation;
```

everything I try doesn't work :(

Comment: What means `doesn't work`? Any errors? What happens instead? The `Animation` component is [deprecated](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html). Now you use an [`Animator`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animator.html) instead.

Comment: so how can i add animator and set it a controller in runtime?

Comment: You can add it to a `GameObject` using `Animator animator = obj.AddComponent<Animator>()`. please also have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554153/how-to-add-a-animator-controller-to-a-character-at-runtime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Animator Controller to a character at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34554153/how-to-add-a-animator-controller-to-a-character-at-runtime)